# Upload multiple images giving a unique name based on the previous uploaded value

Tags: php, arrays, image, file, laravel

I'm trying to upload multiple images but give it a unique name based on the previous uploaded value.

Problem : If I add a Sleep(3), The sequence will be right but some images still wont be uploaded maybe because it's sleeping?

If i dont sleep , the value will be 1 then 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3

How do I wait for move_uploaded_file to complete before moving on? it doesnt seem to be doing that.

```
$files = $_FILES['fileselect'];
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                    //Check Database for Latest File "Name" Count

                    //TODO , verify Orderby
                    $node = DB::table('product_options')->where('product_id', Input::get('productID'))->orderby('created_at','desc')->first();


                    if($node){
                        //If extra image already exist
                        $keywords = preg_split("/[_]+/", $node->image);

                        var_dump($keywords);
                        $fn = Input::get('productID').'_'.($keywords[1]+1).'_extra'.'.jpg';
                        $returnID = Option::create(array('image'=>'productImg/'.$fn,'product_id' =>Input::get('productID')));
                        move_uploaded_file($file[0],'productImg/' . $fn);



                        echo("<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>");

                    }else{

                        $fn = Input::get('productID').'_1_extra'.'.jpg';
                        $returnID = Option::create(array('image'=>'productImg/'.$fn,'product_id' =>Input::get('productID')));
                        move_uploaded_file($file[0],'productImg/' . $fn);
                        echo ("<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>");
                    }
            }
```

Without Sleep, Echo would return this

```
File 52_1_extra.jpg uploaded.

array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "productImg/52" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(9) "extra.jpg" }
File 52_2_extra.jpg uploaded.

array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "productImg/52" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(9) "extra.jpg" }
File 52_2_extra.jpg uploaded.

array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "productImg/52" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(9) "extra.jpg" }
File 52_2_extra.jpg uploaded.

array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "productImg/52" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(9) "extra.jpg" }
File 52_2_extra.jpg uploaded.
```

With Sleep Echo would return it in Sequence (Correct) BUT MISSING IMAGES (Half of it) inside my folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must control with a variable the increment, something like this:

```
$files = $_FILES['fileselect'];
$i = 0;
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                    //Check Database for Latest File "Name" Count

                    //TODO , verify Orderby
                    $node = DB::table('product_options')->where('product_id', Input::get('productID'))->orderby('created_at','desc')->first();


                    if($node){
                        //If extra image already exist
                        $keywords = preg_split("/[_]+/", $node->image);

                        var_dump($keywords);

if($i == 0) {
$i += $keywords[1] + 1;
}
else {
++$i;
}

                        $fn = Input::get('productID').'_'. $i .'_extra'.'.jpg';
                        $returnID = Option::create(array('image'=>'productImg/'.$fn,'product_id' =>Input::get('productID')));
                        move_uploaded_file($file[0],'productImg/' . $fn);



                        echo("<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>");

                    }else{

                        $fn = Input::get('productID').'_1_extra'.'.jpg';
                        $returnID = Option::create(array('image'=>'productImg/'.$fn,'product_id' =>Input::get('productID')));
                        move_uploaded_file($file[0],'productImg/' . $fn);
                        echo ("<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>");
                    }
            }
```

Comment: I dont think i have a choice but do this :( so weird, database too slow?